# How to translate "Relever une prescription" from French to German?

Tags: translation, french

How do you say in German when a nurse becomes aware of a medical prescription and prepares everything according to what the doctor asks?

In French we say "relever une prescription". The action itself is called "une relève infirmière".

Anyone knows how to translate this into German?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In German there are two different meanings for *"prescription"* depending on what a medical doctor prescribed:

1. [Das (ärztliche) Rezept](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Rezept)
   Whenever a doctor prescribes a medication we call this *"Rezept"*. It includes both, ready made pharmaceuticals or a recipy for an individual drug preparation. This prescription then is usually given to a pharmacist using the verb *"[einlösen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/einloesen)"*:

   > Das Rezept wurde in der Apotheke **eingelöst**.

   In the context of nursing we can also use the verb *"[richten](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/richten)"* or *"[herrichten](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/herrichten)"* whenever a drug was prepared by a nurse to be given to a patient.

   > Schwester Ute muss morgens immer als erstes die Medikamente **richten**.
   >   Weil die Spritzen noch nicht **hergerichtet** waren, musste der Patient noch warten.
2. [Die (ärztliche) Verordnung](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Verordnung)

   When there is no medication involved but rather other procedures, such as in your example advice to as nurse, or other medical personel was prescribed, we use *"verordnen/Verordnung"*. This will then be accompanied with the verbs *"[ausführen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/ausfuehren)"*, or less common *"[befolgen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/befolgen)"*:

   > Die Krankenschwester konnte die Verordnung nicht **ausführen**.
3. [Anweisung](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Anweisung), [Rat](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Rat)

   These nouns are also possible for advice from a medical doctor but usually not used in the context of a *prescription*. *"Anweisung"* being similarily authoritative as *"Verordnung"*, whereas *"Rat"* is a less binding advice.

   > Der Patient hat gegen ärztlichen Rat die Klinik verlassen.